# Right way to handle exceptions in Java microservice (REST) app

Tags: java, rest, microservices, resteasy

I'm developing this Java RESTEASY application oriented to microservice pattern, i use methods like this to handle my exceptions:

```
@Path("/find/{id}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response retrieveItemById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    int id;
    try {       
        itemDTO result = service.getItem(id);
        return Response.ok(result).build();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }   
    
}
```

Somebody told me that this method to handle exception (in this case item not found exception) is wrong, but I can't figure out why.

What is the right way to handle exception such as item not found, creation failed, updated failed ...  in a REST oriented application?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends. Exceptions should be used for programming errors. These type of exception should not be caught, because this hides programming errors. If an exception is not a programming error and the program can continue executing, then you might consider catching it and returning some meaningful result. In your care, you are catching both exceptions that might indicate programming errors and exceptions that can be caught to return different values.

Comment: You need ControllerAdvice https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: @DmitriiBykov It's not Spring though.

Comment: Yeah, it is not spring.

Comment: @Ray09 you can approach this by implementing your own `ExceptionMapper` where you define direct mapping of a custom Java exception to HTTP error response. It should be available in a JAX-RS compliant runtime (which RESTEASY is AFAIK). [Here is](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6523) the reference implementation in Jersey